# Grouping by sample for statistical test

Tags: r, data-analysis

I'm attempting to do a one-way anova test to see if different readers have an affect on measured age from a fish ear bone. Every reader measured the same samples, and I'm trying to group the samples and then run an anova over whether reader affects age within each sample.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
Sample <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C" )
Age <- c(4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 2, 4)
reader_ID <- rep(1:3, each = 3)

df <- data.frame(Sample, Age, reader_ID)
```

```
one_way <- aov(Age ~ reader_ID, data = df)
summary(one_way)
```

This is just comparing reader to age and not taking sample into consideration.

How would I group the samples to analyse age and reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your nested data structure, you’ll likely want to use a mixed model. e.g., you can fit a mixed linear model with random intercepts for sample using `lme4::lmer()`:

```
library(lme4)
library(broom.mixed)

mdl <- lmer(Age ~ reader_ID + (1 | Sample), data = df) 

# model summary
glance(mdl)
```

```
# A tibble: 1 × 7
   nobs sigma logLik   AIC   BIC REMLcrit df.residual
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
1   300  2.32  -684. 1375. 1390.    1367.         296
```

```
# coefficients
tidy(mdl, conf.int = TRUE)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 8
  effect   group    term            estimate std.error statis…¹ conf.…² conf.h…³
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 fixed    <NA>     (Intercept)      4.98      0.291      17.1   4.41    5.55   
2 fixed    <NA>     reader_ID       -0.00776   0.00465    -1.67 -0.0169  0.00134
3 ran_pars Sample   sd__(Intercept)  0.187    NA          NA    NA      NA      
4 ran_pars Residual sd__Observation  2.32     NA          NA    NA      NA      
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​statistic, ²​conf.low, ³​conf.high
```

*Expanded example data:*

```
set.seed(13)
Sample <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 100)
Age <- sample(1:8, 300, replace = TRUE)
reader_ID <- rep(1:100, each = 3)
df <- data.frame(Sample, Age, reader_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Took a while to understand the outputs for a linear mixed model, but this really helped.

Comment: You bet. Sounds like you figured it out but the key test here would be the fixed effect of `reader_id` -- so `B = -1.67, 95% CI = [-0.017, 0.001]`.